# Saving Vector Layer as KML with PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, vector, convert, kml

I am aware that it is possible, in QGIS, to save your Vector Layer as a KML manually, however, I want to know if there is anyway I can do this programmatically from an external Python Script that I run from PyScripter.

I am aware ArcPy has that functionality, however, I am looking for a PyQGIS Solution.

Here is how I can do it with ArcPy using the Conversion Tool Set Layer to KML

```py
...
Layer = Output_Layer
Output_File =  r"C:Users\path\KMZ.kmz"

# Process: Layer To KML
arcpy.LayerToKML_conversion(Layer, Output_File, "0", "false", "DEFAULT","1024", "96", "CLAMPED_TO_GROUND")  
print "Layer to KMZ Conversion Complete"
print Output_Layer + " is now a .kmz"
```

or if there is a Python Library that will allow me to convert a shapefile to a KML/KMZ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- If you're running Pyscripter **inside** QGIS, you could try using the following script:

  ```
  from qgis.core import QgsVectorFileWriter, QgsVectorLayer

  data_source = r"path/to/shapefile"
  layer = QgsVectorLayer(data_source, "layer_name", "ogr")
  output_layer = r"C:/Users/path/KML"
  QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer, output_layer, "utf-8", None, "KML")

  print "Layer to KML Conversion Complete"
  print output_layer + " is now a .kml"
  ```

---

- For **outside** QGIS, the following is the script I use which I run from the *OSGeo4W Shell* program (I don't have Pyscripter to test this):

  ```
  import os, sys, glob
  from qgis.core import *
  from qgis.gui import *
  from PyQt4.QtGui import *

  from os.path import expanduser
  home = expanduser("~")

  QgsApplication( [], False, home + "/AppData/Local/Temp" )

  QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C://OSGeo4W64//apps//qgis", True)
  app = QApplication([])
  QgsApplication.initQgis()

  sys.path.append(home + '/.qgis2/python/plugins')
  from processing.core.Processing import Processing
  Processing.initialize()
  from processing.tools import *

  data_source = r"path/to/shapefile"
  layer = QgsVectorLayer(data_source, "layer_name", "ogr")
  output_layer = r"C:/Users/path/KML"
  QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer, output_layer, "utf-8", None, "KML")
  print "Layer to KML Conversion Complete"
  print output_layer + " is now a .kml"

  QgsApplication.exitQgis()
  app.exit()
  ```

Comment: Hi Joseph, Can you tell me please how can I select some fields from attribute fiels in the layer? thank you

Comment: @Joseph  - I get a 'argument 4 has unexpected type 'NoneType' error when I leave the 4th argument as None . Instead, using layer.crs() (the vector layer's QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem object) works for me in QGIS 3.8